# How to plot three values with different datetime in one graph using python?

Tags: python, csv, datetime, time

Here I have one csv file with different values and date_time. I wrote the code and run it. Then it gave me an error  time data '8/6/2018 6:45' does not match format ' %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'
I want to plot this different three values in one graph. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?
Here is my code:

```
condition = ""
date_time  = []
x1 = []
x2 = []
x3 = []
def convertTime(s):
  tm = time.strptime(s, " %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
  return datetime.datetime(date.tm_year,date.tm_mon, date.tm_mday, tm.tm_hour, tm.tm_min, tm.tm_sec)
with open('data43.csv','r') as csv_file:
csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
 row_num = 0
for row in csv_data:
 if(row_num == 0):
  condition = row[0]
elif(row_num > 2): #Data starts here
  if(row[0] != ''):
    date_time.append(convertTime(row[0]))
  if(row[1] != ''):
    x1.append(int(row[1]))
  if(row[2] != ''):
    x2.append(int(row[2]))
  if(row[3] != ''):
    x3.append(int(row[3]))
row_num = row_num + 1
fig1 = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig1.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax.plot(date_time,x1)
ax.stem(date_time,x2,'C1--','C1o',linefmt=None, markerfmt=None, basefmt=None)
ax.stem(date_time,x3,'C2--','C2o',linefmt=None, markerfmt=None, basefmt=None)
ax.legend()
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'))
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('k')
leg = plt.legend( loc = 'upper right')
plt.draw() # Draw the figure so you can find the positon of the legend. 
bb = leg.get_bbox_to_anchor().inverse_transformed(ax.transAxes)
xOffset = 0.3
bb.x0 += xOffset
bb.x1 += xOffset
leg.set_bbox_to_anchor(bb, transform = ax.transAxes)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [20,20]
ax.plot(style='.-')
plt.show()
```

[image]

error :

[image]

I put datetime as :

[image]

so I include seconds as :00 after that I read this csv file.

If I changed time into 12 hours reading then what will happened ?
like this

[image]

Comment: maybe it's because your data has no seconds value? Just seems the most obvious to me. Python is literally telling you what's wrong with it here

Comment: `error time data '8/6/2018 6:45' does not match format ' %d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S` yeah, because your date has no values for `%S`

Comment: Did you read the error?

Comment: @Jab yes I read the error. Then I changed it without%S then still it gave me same error

Comment: @Nihal yes same error I got, then I changed it. same error came

Comment: `%H` is looking for a 2 digit time. Some of your times have 1 digit. same with the `%m`months

Comment: Is there an easy way to reformat the data? just make it all 2 digits or you will need to do more work to fix the data in python

Comment: @Jab I suggested another format to time. Can you look at it any suggestions can you give me?

Comment: @Jab actually I want to plot graph according to this format.

Comment: If you’re going to suggest formats suggest ones that you can either read with strptime or ones that you can convert to a strptimeable format in python. Otherwise you’re going to need to change it to be strptime parseable or use an external library like arrow or pendulum. Make a couple of searches and you’ll see there’s other answers that get either done.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have an error with the data, not the python file.

`8/6/2018 6:45` Does not match the format `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S` because there are no seconds.

I would test with a `:00` added to your time data and test again.

Comment: @SimplaeBinary I already put seconds as :00 but still it gave me this error